# How to get the Object_Id from COM Object in Enterprise Architect

Tags: python, enterprise-architect, win32com, comobject

I tried to find a string in the content of the element of Enterprise Architect using python. I read the excel column by column and search the string in the EAP using SQL query.

**Code**

```
App = win32com.client.Dispatch(EAId)
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row):
  firstline = sheet['E' + str(row)].value.strip().splitlines()[0]
  reqCollection = App.Repository.GetElementSet("select Object_ID " + " from t_object where t_object.Note like '" + firstline + "*' and t_object.name like 'SRC*'", 2)

if len(reqCollection) > 0:
  print(reqCollection[0])
  #print(reqCollection[0].Object_ID) Error
  #print(reqCollection[0].Name)  Error
```

I am able to get the elements from the Query but the problem is I am not able to get the Object_Id or name of the Object. The above code is giving `<COMObject <unknown>>` as a result. How can I get the Object ID from the COMObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can index an EA.Collection like that.

As always it helps to read the documentation:

- [EA.Collection](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/automation/collection.html)
- [EA.Element](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/automation/element2.html)

You can get an item from the collection using the operation `GetAt(index)`, or you can do a `foreach` to iterate the elements in the collection.

Also EA.Element does not have a property called `Object_ID`, that is the name of the column in the database. The object ID can be retrieved from the property `ElementID`

Comment: No, not "don't think". It's just not possible. You get an object in return and that has an operation `GetAt`.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens@ qwerty_so Thanks for your solution. It's worked, I know GetElementSet return value is EA.Collection but I assumed it's a Collection in python so used direct indexing instead of GetAt.

Answer (score 1):

I oversaw the Python. You can do

```
for elem in reqCollection:
   print (elem.name) # for example
```

Works for all collections (I used so far) returned by EA.

Comment: yes, it's working. Actually, it's my mistake I used Object_ID instead of ElementID so I was getting the error.